# Remove one object from JS Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have the following function:

```
private removeOneCard(id) {
  this.cards = this.cards.filter(
    card => card.id != id);
}
```

Which I have been able to filter out all of the objects that have the same id. The issue is that I have a few objects with the same id (its for a card game). Rather than making duplicates of all the cards, I just keep track of how many of the same type are still in the deck vs in peoples hands.

How can I tell this function to filter only one of the cards with the same id? As in, find a card with the id of 5, cut that one out of my hand, then keep all the other cards in my hand?

Comment: I would say you have problem with logic. If you have list of objects no matter how you show it for users but for you (developer) each item should have unique id. It will save you from a lot of problems in the future

Comment: That is fair I suppose... It isn't for a client or anything just a quick and dirty thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is an `Array.prototype` function that accomplishes what you want.

This is probably the most succinct declarative approach.

```
private removeOneCard(id) {
  // Grab the index of the first card whose ID matches the input ID
  const removeIdx = this.cards.findIndex((card) => card.id === id);
  // Remove that index from the array
  this.cards = this.cards.filter((card, idx) => idx !== removeIdx);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can separate it into 2 steps:

1. Find the index of the first occurrence.
2. Remove the object

Demo:

```
// Find index
var index = cards.findIndex(function (c) {
    return c.id === cardId;
})

// Remove if exists
if (index >= 0) {
    cards.splice(index, 1)
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/uczzqcqd/1)